# Delphi Web Script: How to call global TForm object's property in script?

Tags: delphi, dwscript

I've registered TForm class and its 'caption' property, then I register a global variable:

```
NewGlobal := DwsUnit.Variables.Add;
NewGlobal.Name := 'MainForm';
NewGlobal.DataType := 'TForm';
NewGlobal.OnReadVar := GlobalReadProc;
```

GlobalReadProc code:

```
GlobalReadProc(Info: TProgramInfo;var Value: Variant);
begin
    TVarData(Value).VType := varUnknown;
    IUnknown(TVarData(Value).VUnknown) := TForm(Form1);
end;
```

In the script I call my MainForm variables property

```
MainForm.Caption := ''DWS Script in work'';
```

DWScript shows exception:

> interface not supported.

What am I doing wrong?
(I use IUnknown because I've seen that typecast in VarCopySafe procedure, and I get an exception when VType is not varUnknown)

Comment: Have you tried varByRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value should be the script representation of your object; An `IScriptObj`.

The following works for me:

```
GlobalReadProc(ProgramInfo: TProgramInfo; var Value: Variant);
var
  Info: IInfo;
begin
  Info := ProgramInfo.ResultVars.GetConstructor('Create', Form1).Call;
  Value := Info.ScriptObj;
end;
```

Personally I would use an Instance or a function instead of a global variable.